# Multi- way regression model?

Tags: regression, model

A relative novice to modelling here...
Is there a way to create a "3way" regression that uses 'background' info which is not related to the X but affects the Y?
So in a usual arrangement I have dependent Y (in fact only one variable), let's say it is lm, luminosity of an object, an independent X, where each column is a physchem descriptor for the object and each row is a different object.
In a conventional way I can regress luminosity on descriptots, say using PLS.
Now, let's imagine I have additional background info I want to implicate in the model, say, conditions of temp, humidity, pressure, etc. They will affect the luminosity but they don't affect the descriptors, which are constant for each object.
Is there a way to have a model that kind of regresses on both, descriptors and conditions?
This is to predict luminosity given object's properties and conditions.
Many thanks.

*I'm using luminosity here as a simplification placeholder; the thing I'm afer is a bit different, but still an extensive property.

Comment: A standard approach would be some kind of regression model that models the expected outcome for Y as a function of X and additional things, let's call them Z. E.g. as a linear model EY = beta0 + beta1*X + beta2*Z1 + beta3*Z3 ... (or some kind of splines/non-linear functions). Is that what you have in mind? If so, that's a very standard thing to do, if not, can you clarify how what you have in mind differs?

Comment: @Björn  thx, yes, I suppose multiple regression would be the simplest thing to try to combine X and Z into a new variable space. However, I was thinking about dimentionality reduction on both X and Z. Also I suppose PLS-like approach or any other advanced model is more robust compared to MLR, error-wise.

Comment: On the second thought.. maybe I'm overthinking it... maybe I CAN just combine descriptors with conditions, having descriptors repeated in blocks while varying only conditions.. My naive thinking though is descriptors and conditions should belong to different spaces somehow. Almost like first regressing on descriptors for each condition and then regressing this on conditions... I don't know..